# Plotting a histogram in ggplot2 results in memory error (only 418 data points)

Tags: r, memory, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram with 2 sets of data using ggplot2. My dataset has 418 values to plot, with 2 groups of data (so there will be 2 sets of coloured bars on my histogram). Annoyingly I can't reproduce the problem with the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,1], fill=iris[,5])) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth=.5,alpha=.5)
```

This creates a histogram fine. When I try it on my data I get:

```
Error : cannot allocate vector of size 4.0 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In anyDuplicated.default(breaks) :
  Reached total allocation of 16366Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In anyDuplicated.default(breaks) :
  Reached total allocation of 16366Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In anyDuplicated.default(breaks) :
  Reached total allocation of 16366Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In anyDuplicated.default(breaks) :
  Reached total allocation of 16366Mb: see help(memory.size)
Error in UseMethod("scale_dimension") : 
  no applicable method for 'scale_dimension' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I have 16GB of memory, so producing a plot with 418 data points shouldn't be an issue.

Any help much appreciated.

---

It turns out that my data still won't plot, even when referring to column names. I think this is due to the range in the data. After log transforming the data, the histogram plots. It seems that ggplot2 or R as a whole doesn't like a range of 1-165476109 which is understandable...

Answer (score 5):

Your code should look like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5,alpha=.5)
```

[image]

The reason is that arguments inside the `aes()` are evaluated in the environment of your data. This means your mapping should point to column names in your data, i.e. `x=Sepal.Length`).

When you write the `aes()` call in the way you did, you are trying to tell `ggplot` to map 150 different variables to `x`, and similarly to map 150 different variables to `fill` - this clearly isn't what you had in mind.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your pointers to improve my code. It turns out that my data still won't plot, even when referring to column names. I think this is due to the range in the data. After log transforming the data, the histogram plots. Thanks.